# .desktop file does not show the icon in applications

Tags: launcher, icons, eclipse, .desktop

I have created a `.desktop` file for Eclipse and put it in `.local/share/applications` in applications launcher the icon of app is not showing up.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Oxygen_Eclipse
Comment=Eclipse Integrated Development Environment
Icon= /home/amir/IDE/OXYGEN/eclipse/icon.xpm 
Exec= /home/amir/IDE/OXYGEN/eclipse/eclipse 
Terminal=false
Categories=Development;IDE;Java;
StartupWMClass=Oxygen_Eclipse
```

I have the same `.desktop` file for eclipse Luna (with path to luna folder) and that one shows the icon. I have tried `.png` file and another `.xmp` icon none of them work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had a similar issue and I fixed it by removing a stray whitespace character at the end of the `Icon` line. It looks like there is whitespace in you paths, what happens if you try

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Oxygen_Eclipse
Comment=Eclipse Integrated Development Environment
Icon=/home/amir/IDE/OXYGEN/eclipse/icon.xpm
Exec=/home/amir/IDE/OXYGEN/eclipse/eclipse
Terminal=false
Categories=Development;IDE;Java;
StartupWMClass=Oxygen_Eclipse
```

Comment: FWIW, I had managed to get my custom app to show up.  It failed to run.  I corrected the mistake but now when I type the name in the search bar it does not show up.  My typo was in the Exec statement.  I did check to see if I had any blank lines or spaces at the end of text. I do not.

Comment: created an account here to say thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I made the mistake of putting the Exec and Icon value in "'s when I removed them everything work correctly